# SQL Server : add a character in a string between 2 comma-separated values

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
declare @qry nvarchar(max)
set @qry='IType, INum, IDate, PO, FCode, Tx, Fr, TI, Not'

select @qry = 'select distinct ti.ID,' + @qry +
              ' from tblInfo ti inner join tblheadr th on ti.IA=1 AND ti.BId = ' +
              CAST(@BId as varchar) + ' AND th.CUId =' + CAST(@UserID as varchar)
```

Now I want my query as

```
select distinct 
    ti.ID, ti.IType, ti.INum, ti.IDate, ti.PO, ti.FCode, ti.Tx, ti.Fr, ti.TI, ti.Not 
from 
    tblInfo ti 
inner join 
    tblheadr th on ti.IA = 1 AND ti.BId = 285 and th.CUId = 2
```

I need to add `'ti.'` for each value in `@qry`..

Can you suggest me how to separate it add `ti.` in between `@qry` ?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a shorter solution:

```
SET @qry = 'IType, INum, IDate, PO, FCode, Tx, Fr, TI, [Not]'
SET @qry = 'ti.' + REPLACE(@qry, ', ', ', ti.')
```

You should put `Not` in square brackets cause it's a reserved SQL keyword.

Comment: It's shorter, but the query generated won't run :p My first answer was just about as short, before I decided to fix the other issues.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select @qry =   
    'select distinct ti.ID,' 
    + replace(replace(replace(@qry, ', Not', ', [Not]'), @qry, 'ti.' + @qry), ', ',', ti.') 
    +' from tblInfo ti inner join tblheadr th on ti.IA=1 AND ti.BId = ' 
    + QUOTENAME(CAST(@BId as varchar(max)), '''') 
    + ' AND th.CUId =' 
    + QUOTENAME(CAST(@UserID as varchar(max)),'''')
```

You really should specify size for the varchar casts, and also note that `not`is a keyword that needs to be escaped, so I added that. Most likely you also need to use QUOTENAME to enclose the parameter values in quotes (I added that too).

The resulting`@qry`variable will be this:

```
select distinct 
  ti.ID,IType, ti.INum, ti.IDate, ti.PO, ti.FCode, ti.Tx, ti.Fr, ti.TI, ti.[Not] 
from tblInfo ti 
inner join tblheadr th on ti.IA=1 AND ti.BId = 'BidA' AND th.CUId ='UserA'
```

If the variables are declared as:

```
declare @userid nvarchar(max) = 'UserA'
declare @bid nvarchar(max) = 'BidA'
```

On a side note: looking at your join between tblInfo and tblHeadr it seems like there's no join condition, only conditions on the separate tables (that should probably be written in a WHERE clause). Maybe you forgot the join `th.? = ti.?` ?